# How to filter links dynamically in a node-link network in protovis?

Tags: html, protovis

My code is based on protovis sample code for [Force-Directed Layouts](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/force.html). I would like to add the ability to dynamically filter links with a slider based on their value. I already have a basic slider working. What I don't know is how to update the Network object so that only renders only the links that have a value greater than the value on the slider. Does anyone know how to do this?

The code to create the graph is

```
var minLinkValue = 2;
var vis = new pv.Panel()
    .width(w)
    .height(h)
    .fillStyle("white")
    .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.pan())
    .event("mousewheel", pv.Behavior.zoom());

var force = vis.add(pv.Layout.Force);
force.nodes(grafica.nodes);
force.links(grafica.links.filter(function(d) { return d.value > minLinkValue} ));

force.link.add(pv.Line);

force.node.add(pv.Dot)
    .fillStyle(function(d) { return color(d) })         
    .strokeStyle(function() { return this.fillStyle().darker() })
    .lineWidth(1)
    .title(function(d) { return d.nodeName })
    .visible(function(d) { return d.linkDegree > 0 })
    .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag());

vis.render();
```

I create the slider with html5

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="20" value="2" step="1" onchange="setAndShowNewValue(this.value)" />
<span id="range">2</span>
```

And set the new minimum value with

```
    function setAndShowNewValue(newValue)
    {
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
        minLinkValue = newValue;
    }
```

Thanks,
Raul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was in a thread at [Protovis google group](http://groups.google.com/group/protovis/browse_thread/thread/af0e05c496f66eb4/641cf85269631dc0)

So, what I did is to create the following function and call it after updating the minimum value allowed for a link:

```
function filterLinks() { 
        force.links(grafica.links.filter(function(d) { return d.value > 
minLinkValue} )); 
        force.reset(); 
}
```

Then I fixed the code in protovis as suggested in the mentioned thread